# Dictionary map in a handler function for class methods

Tags: python, class, design-patterns, structure, handler

I have a class that accepts a different number of inputs but achieves the same goal (Same output). It's a complex class and is used heavily for an API. I built a class handler that accepts inputs and maps them into the function based on the API request.

I'm not sure if this type of design is maintainable or if it's going to present other issues. So I have these inquiries:

1. Is this design maintainable and scalable?
2. Is this error-tolerant?
3. Can I improve it?
4. Am I following a design similar to any accepted design pattern?
5. Any advice?

Please take a look at this very simplified code design:

Handler:

```
def class_handler(class_usage_type, class_object, kwargs):
    # Method inputs and procedures are different but output is the same
    Usage_FUNC_MAP = { 
        'use_method_x': class_object.method_x, 
        'use_method_y': class_object.method_y,
        'use_method_z': class_object.method_z,
        # ...
    }
    
    try:
        result = Usage_FUNC_MAP[class_usage_type](**kwargs)
        
    except Exception as e:
        result = {
            'output_elem1': kwargs
            'output_elem2': f'Error: {e}',
            'output_elem3': f'Error {e}'
        }

    finally:
        return result
```

Class

```
class some_class():
    # ...init
    def method_x(self, param1_for_x, param2_for_x):
        # ...procedure for x
        return same_output

    def method_y(self, param1_for_y):
        # ...procedure for y
        return same_output

    def method_z(self, param1_for_z, param2_for_z, param3_for_z, param4_for_z):
        # ...procedure for z
        return same_output

    # ...
```

API

```
# Main is in a different file as an API
# Route 1 for x
# ...
params_for_x = {"param1_for_x": '...', "param2_for_x": '...'}
result_for_x = class_handler(class_usage_type='use_method_x', class_object=some_class, kwargs=params)
#...

# Route 2 for y
# ...
params_for_y = {"param1_for_y": '...'}
result_for_y = class_handler(class_usage_type='use_method_y', class_object=some_class, kwargs=params)
# ...

# Route 3 for z
# ...
params_for_z = {"param1_for_z": '...', "param2_for_z": '...', "param3_for_z": '...', "param4_for_z": '...'}
result_for_z = class_handler(class_usage_type='use_method_z', class_object=some_class, kwargs=params)
# ...

# ...
```

Comment: Why do you need the class handler? You could also access `result_for_x = some_class.method_x(params)` ?

Comment: It looks like this is question(s) more suitable for [codereview.se]

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel Handling the differences in input parameters in one place which might produce errors instead of handling them in each function in the class. Another reason is using function "names" with respect to the API usage

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of that function map, you could use the `getattr()` function and pass the function name as a string.
Example:

```
def class_handler(class_usage_type, class_object, kwargs):

    try:
        result = getattr(class_object(), class_usage_type)(**kwargs)
        
    except Exception as e:
        result = {
            'output_elem1': kwargs,
            'output_elem2': f'Error: {e}',
            'output_elem3': f'Error {e}'
        }

    finally:
        return result

class some_class():
    # ...init
    def method_x(self, param1_for_x, param2_for_x):
        # ...procedure for x
        return same_output


params_for_x = {"param1_for_x": '...', "param2_for_x": '...'}
result_for_x = class_handler(class_usage_type='method_x', class_object=some_class, kwargs=params_for_x)
```